# OAuth 1 Online Signature Tester?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-1.0a

I know there is an ongoing battle about OAuth1 vs OAuth2 and Google seem to have taken the side of v2 and deprecated their super useful online testing tool that was hosted here...

https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html

We still use OAuth 1.0a and it suits our needs perfectly. Does anyone know of an alternative online test tool for verifying signatures?

Comment: Did you try jwt.io

Answer (score 1):

Since this question came up when I searched for it and even though it's probably too late for the asker:

I couldn't find any online tools, but Postman does a great job of allowing you to test OAuth1. They have easy to follow instructions as well:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#oauth-10

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this tool in The Future, the archived copy on Wayback Machine still functions: https://web.archive.org/web/20160430150356/https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html

This is the final version before it joined the Google Graveyard in May 2016.